# JS script to translate a REST call result into array

Tags: javascript, rest, vmware

I'm not good with JS.
I need a script that translate the result data object from a VMWARE REST call into an array containing objects with properties ‘name’ and ‘value’. The input data is provided as ‘data’ and the result should be put on the global variable ‘results’.
Example:

```
for(var x=0;x < data.length; x++) {
  results.push({name: data[x].title,value:data[x].id});
}
```

the results from the REST call is like that:

```
curl -H "vmware-api-session-id: a32d95dc6f1e88c749c0a0754cf87724" https://VCSA/rest/vcenter/network -k
{"value":[{"name":"D_vMotion_631","type":"DISTRIBUTED_PORTGROUP","network":"dvportgroup-28"}]}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: So what's wrong with the for-loop in the question?

Comment: with the example I do not get any results

Comment: You need to show more of the code in question. How is the call to the API done in your JavaScript code?

Comment: the call is with this command: curl -H "vmware-api-session-id: a32d95dc6f1e88c749c0a0754cf87724" https://VCSA/rest/vcenter/network -k

Comment: But the curl command is executed from the command line, right?

Comment: Actually it's an application that runs this command via ssh cli right.

Comment: What does your JavaScript code look like before the for-loop in your question?

Comment: at the end I managed in that way: `for(var x=0;x < data.data.length; x++) {
  results.push({name: data.data[x].name,value:data.data[x].value});
}`